# Can I expedite Schengen visa at Italian consulate in San Francisco

Tags: visas, schengen, san-francisco, consulates

I made the mistake of booking the tickets and accommodation without checking the consulate's appointment availability.

Now I realize there is no slot available at Italian Consulate in SFO before my departure date. Is there a way I could expedite the visa processing ?

Comment: There is very often a 2 to 3 month wait for an appointment to the Italian consulate in San Francisco. The same is true of consulates in the US to many other Schengen states. You are well advised to apply at least 3 months advance of travel whenever possible. In any case, all of the Schengen states warn visa applicants _not_ to book flights or hotels until _after_ receiving a visa.

Answer (score 7):

Answering if someone is looking for answer.

Italian consulate website adds new slots (I guess these slots are a result of automatic cancellations in their system) everyday at 12 midnight Italy time. I made sure to login at that time and managed to find a slot well under a week.

Comment: You have created two separate accounts. You may want to get them merged.